# Mapping nested List Property of items in MySQL query to objects

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, ado.net

I want to get the details of a product and the List of its pictures for that product. The code below works fine but it returns only 1 picture of the product instead. I am having issues mapping the result of MySQL query to C# objects.

Here is what I have tried so far

```cs
public ProductModel GetProductDetail(uint product_id)
{
    var cmd = this.MySqlDatabase.Connection.CreateCommand() as MySqlCommand;
    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT products.*, images.* FROM products LEFT JOIN images ON products.product_id= images.product_id WHERE products.product_id = @product_id LIMIT 0,1";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_id", product_id);
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            return new ProductModel()
            {
                product_id = reader.GetValue<UInt32>("product_id"),
                subcategory_id = reader.GetValue<UInt32>("subcategory_id"),
                product_name = reader.GetValue<String>("product_name"),
                description = reader.GetValue<String>("description"),
                is_recent = reader.GetValue<Boolean>("is_recent"),
                is_popular = reader.GetValue<Boolean>("is_popular"),
                is_available = reader.GetValue<Boolean>("is_available"),
                price = reader.GetValue<Decimal>("price"),
                overall_rating = reader.GetValue<Double>("overall_rating"),
                views = reader.GetValue<UInt32>("views"),
                people_rated = reader.GetValue<UInt32>("people_rated"),
                date_posted = reader.GetValue<DateTime>("date_posted"),
                Images = new List<ImagesModel>
                {
                    new ImagesModel
                    {
                        imageurl = reader.GetValue<String>("imageurl"),
                        created_date = reader.GetValue<DateTime>("created_date")
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    return null;
}
```

Also below is the JSON result I get

```
{
    "code": 1,
    "message": "Product found",
    "document": {
        "product_id": 11,
        "subcategory_id": 22,
        "product_name": "Lead Guitar",
        "description": "Unde dolor sed natus velit omnis doloribus consequatur adipisci quos quasi laboriosam optio aut beatae; cupiditate modi animi hic non qui consequatur, natus voluptatem quae ea quia est doloremque possimus.",
        "is_recent": true,
        "is_popular": false,
        "is_available": false,
        "price": 1942.51,
        "overall_rating": 3,
        "views": 520,
        "people_rated": 350,
        "date_posted": "2005-05-08T06:21:03",
        "images": [
            {
                "imageurl": "http://www.thetehad.es/but/teerted/anne/ionhe.png",
                "created_date": "2021-08-28T12:33:01"
            },
            .
            .
            . 
            // THERE SHOULD BE MORE IMAGES HERE BUT I AM GETTING ONLY ONE
        ]
    }
}
```

Please what am I doing wrong here? Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to get product and images in one query? For single object more efficient to query itself and its images in separate query, there is not select N+1 problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues that need to point out.

**ISSUES**

**First**

```
SELECT products.*, images.* FROM products LEFT JOIN images ON products.product_id= images.product_id WHERE products.product_id = @product_id LIMIT 0,1
```

Your MYSQL query contains `LIMIT 0,1`, which means it will return the first row only.

Using `LEFT JOIN` for this query is not so correct, as by removing `LIMIT 0,1`, it returns 1 x n record(s) where n is the number of images record that has the same `product_id`.

**Second**

```
return new ProductModel()
{
    Images = new List<ImagesModel>
    {
        new ImagesModel
        {
            imageurl = reader.GetValue<String>("imageurl"),
            created_date = reader.GetValue<DateTime>("created_date")
        }
    }
};
```

You create `new ProductModel()` and assign `Images` with `List<ImagesModel>` that contains **one ImagesModel object only**.

**SOLUTION**

For first issue: Split the query into two and using two DataReader:

- First DataReader will only query `Product` record based on ProductID
- Second DataReader will query `Image` records based on ProductID

For second issue: Retrieve image records from second DataReader and using loop to create image object(s)

```
public ProductModel GetProductDetail(uint product_id)
{
    ProductModel product = null;

    using (var productCmd = this.MySqlDatabase.Connection.CreateCommand() as MySqlCommand)
    {
        productCmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = @product_id";
        productCmd.Parameters.Add("@product_id", SqlDbType.int).Value = product_id;

        using (var reader = productCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                product = new ProductModel()
                {
                    product_id = reader.GetValue<UInt32>("product_id"),
                    subcategory_id = reader.GetValue<UInt32>("subcategory_id"),
                    product_name = reader.GetValue<String>("product_name"),
                    description = reader.GetValue<String>("description"),
                    is_recent = reader.GetValue<Boolean>("is_recent"),
                    is_popular = reader.GetValue<Boolean>("is_popular"),
                    is_available = reader.GetValue<Boolean>("is_available"),
                    price = reader.GetValue<Decimal>("price"),
                    overall_rating = reader.GetValue<Double>("overall_rating"),
                    views = reader.GetValue<UInt32>("views"),
                    people_rated = reader.GetValue<UInt32>("people_rated"),
                    date_posted = reader.GetValue<DateTime>("date_posted")  
                };
            }
        }          
    }
           
    if (product == null)
        return null;

    var imageList = new List<ImagesModel>(); 
    using (var imageCmd = this.MySqlDatabase.Connection.CreateCommand() as MySqlCommand)
    {
        imageCmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM images WHERE product_id = @product_id";
        imageCmd.Parameters.Add("@product_id", SqlDbType.int).Value = product_id;

        using (var reader = imageCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                imageList.Add(new ImagesModel
                {
                    imageurl = reader.GetValue<String>("imageurl"),
                    created_date = reader.GetValue<DateTime>("created_date")
                });
            }
        }          
    }
    
    product.Images = imageList;    
    return product;
}
```

Comment: Very impressive. Thumbs up!!! One more question, Does it have performance issue when queried separately?

Comment: Hi @Pat, You're welcome. Didn't test for the code but overall these concepts mentioned could help you to understand the issue and have a guideline to solve it. Hope you find out the solution soon. Thank you.

Comment: It worked like magic. Your answer made the whole process super clear